# Go from JPG to Bitmap then store in a Database

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap

I am developing an android app where I have users upload profile pictures from their phones which are then saved into a database.  What I have so far is I create a bitmap from the user's picture, then I compress it with the bitmap compress function and then my server receives the byte array and stores it into the database.  I can then send the byte array back but I cannot figure out how to convert the byte array into a bitmap again.  Here are some code snippets of what I am doing:

(Here I am just taking a dummy picture from in the app and sending it to the server)

```
Bitmap t = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.j0);
mProtocol.updateUser(t);
```

(The updateUser command)

```
public void updateUser(Bitmap b){
    try {
        mOutput.writeObject(20);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, mSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(Finally, I try to recreate the bitmap from the byte array)

```
Bitmap t = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(user.getProPic(),0, 20000);
```

But after I run the app, the bitmap still remains blank.  Any thoughts of what is going on?

Comment: Um, is there a particular reason why you have hardcoded `20000`, rather than using the actual length of the `byte[]`? Is `t` `null` after `decodeByteArray()`? Have you saved the `byte[]` to a file after downloading it from the server and seen if it is a valid image?

Comment: No but I cannot find out how to find the size of the picture after it is compressed.